# Cordova-plugin-facebook-4: logEvent method not working on iOS

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, facebook-sdk-4.0

I currently have an ionic app, which uses the following plugin: https://github.com/jeduan/cordova-plugin-facebook4 so that users can login to my app using the Facebook SDK, and so that I can track certain custom events, using the logEvent method.

Since it is an ionic app, I have a iOS and an Android build of the app. The custom events are working as expected on the Android platform. The strange thing is that in iOS, when an event is fired, I can clearly see the success event handler being called, indicating success, however, going to the Facebook analytics, I can clearly see that no custom event data is being saved. It tracks the usual app opens etc, it's just that custom events don't seem to be getting recorded for iOS.

Just to be clear any of this logging happens after the user has already logged in, I have heard it only  works for iOS if you are authenticated with FB first.

So I have a generic function first:

```
$scope.fbLogEvent = function(eventName, params, valueToSum) {
    if (valueToSum == null) {
      valueToSum = 1;
    }
    if (!ionic.Platform.is('browser')) {
      return facebookConnectPlugin.logEvent(eventName, params, valueToSum, function(success) {
        return console.info('FB', eventName, 'event has been logged');
      }, function(error) {
        return console.error(error);
      });
    }
  };
```

I then call the following function to do the actual tracking

`$scope.fbLogEvent('item-requested', { item: $scope.item });`

- It works perfectly on Android
- When I add an item on iOS (using Safari developer logging on the app running on my phone), I can see that the success function is called, because it logs the following message: `FB item-requested event has been logged`.
- I have tested this with the latest version of the plugin (just to be sure), but that did not seem to make a difference.

UPDATE 3/3/2017 - for what it's worth, it does seem to pickup these events if they predefined events, as opposed to custom events.

Comment: did you ever find a solution to this? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: Unfortunately not yet, but will be sure to let you know if I find the cause.

Comment: Perhaps you can add your comment here, https://github.com/jeduan/cordova-plugin-facebook4/issues/376 so that the plugin developers can investigate?